# How to append collection as new column to DataFrame with many columns?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, functional-programming, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to append (add) a new column to an existing dataframe with multiple columns.

```
val a = Seq(
  ("10", "MILLER", "1300", "2017-11-03"),
  ("30", "Martin", "1250", "2017-11-21")).toDF("dept_no","emp_name","sal","date")
scala> a.show
+-------+--------+----+----------+
|dept_no|emp_name| sal|      date|
+-------+--------+----+----------+
|     10|  MILLER|1300|2017-11-03|
|     30|  Martin|1250|2017-11-21|
+-------+--------+----+----------+
```

With the above dataframe I'd like to add every element of a collection (be it a regular Scala collection or another single-column DataFrame), e.g.

```
val lst = List("10", "Susan")
```

How to add the elements of `lst` above to the rows of `a` dataframe (one element per row)?

Comment: Thanks @Jacek for the edit, just want to add something, sometimes some member asks for what i have tried, even stackoverflow says while asking the question please elaborate your effort and what you have tried. some member downvotes if I don't mention my efforts, that is why i added so much extra stuff, also I had a fear of getting marked as "duplicate" :) :)

Comment: Sure. No worries. It's already answered so that's why I "cut the noise". Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's convert `lst` to a DataFrame:

```
val lst = List("10", "Susan").toDF
```

You can use `zip` method of `RDD`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val data = a.rdd.zip(lst.rdd).map { case (l, r) => Row.fromSeq(l.toSeq ++ r.toSeq) }
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
val schema = StructType(a.schema.fields ++ lst.schema.fields)
val solution = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
scala> solution.show
+-------+--------+----+----------+-----+
|dept_no|emp_name| sal|      date|value|
+-------+--------+----+----------+-----+
|     10|  MILLER|1300|2017-11-03|   10|
|     30|  Martin|1250|2017-11-21|Susan|
+-------+--------+----+----------+-----+
```